# How to structure Node/Angular/Socket.io project?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, socket.io, project

I am working on a project that uses AngularJS and Socket.io. I found [this](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io-seed) very nice example of integration.

This is the project structure:

```
app.js                  --> app config
bower.json              --> for bower
package.json            --> for npm
public/                 --> all of the files to be used in on the client side
  css/                  --> css files
    app.css             --> default stylesheet
  img/                  --> image files
  js/                   --> javascript files
    app.js              --> declare top-level app module
    controllers.js      --> application controllers
    directives.js       --> custom angular directives
    filters.js          --> custom angular filters
    services.js         --> custom angular services
  bower_components/
    angular/            --> angular.js
    angular-socket-io/  --> socket.io adapter for angular
routes/
  index.js              --> route for serving HTML pages and partials
  socket.js             --> serve content over a socket
  api.js                --> serve JSON to our AngularJS client
views/
  index.jade            --> main page for app
  layout.jade           --> doctype, title, head boilerplate
  partials/             --> angular view partials (partial jade templates)
    partial1.jade
    partial2.jade
```

in app.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    routes = require('./routes'),
    api = require('./routes/api'),
    socket = require('./routes/socket');

...

// serve index and view partials
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/partials/:name', routes.partials);

// JSON API
app.get('/api/name', api.name);

// redirect all others to the index (HTML5 history)
app.get('*', routes.index);

// Socket.io Communication
io.sockets.on('connection', require('./routes/socket'));
```

Now, while normally I would just put the server logic in `app.js` it seems that here the logic is divided between `api.js`, `socket.js`and `index.js`- I quite like this.

However, let's say that in `socket.js` I need to use something defined in `api.js`.. should I add a `var api = require('./api');` in `socket.js`?

Comment: Have you looked at the generator-angular for Yeoman? This will help you structure your app.

Comment: Yes, the client side is no problem. angular is quite cool :)

Problem was the server side.. I ended up creating modules/objects, importing everything into the `app.js` and passing them by reference to each other (when needed)..  :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up creating modules/objects, importing everything into the app.js and passing them by reference to each other (when needed)..

```
  var mashup = require('./routes/mashupModule'),
  socket = require('./routes/socketModule'),
  browser = require('./routes/browserModule');

  socket.init(server, browser, mashup);
  browser.init(socket, mashup);
```

Not sure whether this is the best way to have some kind of separation in the code.. I am used to Java, and it sucks that in JS it is usually one big source file..

Comment: Actually, one big source file is just one way of doing things. Unlike Java, you can (almost always) do whatever you want and organize things the way that fits your needs. Of course there are best practices and seeds all around, but it's up to you. I think someone downvoted your answer because you provided little information about what you did. Maybe those modules are correctly being imported and being passed by reference, maybe not. Maybe a better explanation or more code would help.